How to detect email clients app installed on user's device?
in my project I use Next js and I have a functionality: I use react-share lib to share the link via mail
When the user clicks on the mail button, his desktop mail client is launched.
The question arises: is it possible to detect that a user, for example, does not have a desktop email client and show an error that it is installed, etc.?
i did smth like this but it's not correct:
export default function Home() {

    const shareUrl = 'https://example.com';
    const subject = 'Check out this website!';
    const body = 'Here is something interesting I found:';

    const handleMailtoClick = () => {
        try {
            window.location.href = `mailto:test@example.com`;
        } catch (error) {
            alert("It looks like you don't have a desktop email client installed. Install the email application and try again.");
        }
    };

    return (
      <div>
          <EmailShareButton url={shareUrl} subject={subject} body={body} onClick={handleMailtoClick} >
              <EmailIcon/>
          </EmailShareButton>
      </div>
  );
}


Leave that for client setup

due to browser security restrictions, there’s no direct way to detect if an email client is installed or if the mailto link successfully opened it

No, you can't and you shouldn't. Because there are too many things that could go wrong. For instance more or less every system does have some sort of mailclient installed by default. But that doesn't mean, the user has ever used or configured it.
